# Should user-generated tags be stored in separate database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm creating a listing type of website (like Kijiji). Each listing can have a bunch of comma separated tags associated with them like: "new york, dogs care, family pet, etc...". Those tags are created by the users themselves when they create a listing. Should I store these in a separate database table and link the table to the main listings table? Or can I store them in a column of the listings table?

What would be the best way?

Thanks

Comment: nth normalization would suggest you would store tags in a separate table.  Actually you would store the tag in a tag table and a relationship between listing and tag in another table.  This would optimize storage space queries when not using the tags, and queries when using them.  It also help you not to have to split string in SQL which can be done but isn't ideal and could eventually support a tag with a common in it if desired.

Comment: The optimal schema for ListingTag many:many mapping table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 1):

The tags should be stored in a `listingTags` table, with one row per listing and per tag.

A comma-separated list is not an appropriate data structure in SQL.  You would only use it if the string were a "blob" that you were never going to look into.  With tags, you undoubtedly want to look into the string, so you can find listings with a particular tag (for instance) or even just get a list of tags that have been used.

Comment: or Listing, Tags, and ListingTagsCrossRef